# Why does mplayer not play my stream?

Tags: https, ffmpeg, soundcloud, mplayer

I wanted to use mplayer (a command line tool) to play a SoundCloud url that I fetched with there official API. The url looks like this

```
https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/qop35iYKlHhs.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiKjovL2NmLW1lZGlhLnNuZGNkbi5jb20vcW9wMzVpWUtsSGhzLjEyOC5tcDMiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE0Njg3NTM4NjB9fX1dfQ__&Signature=OZ4IawmjdU6hEN8KB8e~t3QTy4lBFVBbIDg-a6tuPkb65e0mPskkCFFASkTWbyy5lsaT9IrURan6y70sZhLXPbng1IfkTsGdX1dO938NwVYnKs-BS7IL4TiVFxTBXoKJgmCmUD0qmmGmYqm3YdGZQrP~Sj~mw9~fmtwdHQu0rhl3O-dKsgk497JAR6pMorQs7BSs0XIosV1Mmv2DMD6iifquCWV9Ezq4ekneQ1gfSjVmzjjnKvsxjPpgmU~5DTdewwzlNClVxdzHSQONWM7c0YMGlBcVz97NviaeZOQSCAW8QZS59WULXJBJ9OmEPctWtpe3O0mo-GYjwEkbVGYl9A__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJAGZ7VMH2PFPW6UQ
```

I use the command "mplayer 'url'" to play it but I always get the output:

```
libavformat version 57.25.100 (internal)
https protocol not found, recompile FFmpeg with openssl, gnutls,
or securetransport enabled.
```

Looking which protocols have been installed tells me that I have https input and output support (ffmpeg -protocols):

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.1.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libfaac --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-openssl --enable-libopus --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Supported file protocols:
Input:
  async
  cache
  concat
  crypto
  data
  file
  ftp
  gopher
  hls
  http
  httpproxy
  https
  mmsh
  mmst
  pipe
  rtp
  srtp
  subfile
  tcp
  tls
  udp
  udplite
  unix
  rtmp
  rtmpe
  rtmps
  rtmpt
  rtmpte
Output:
  crypto
  file
  ftp
  gopher
  http
  httpproxy
  https
  icecast
  md5
  pipe
  rtp
  srtp
  tcp
  tls
  udp
  udplite
  unix
  rtmp
  rtmpe
  rtmps
  rtmpt
  rtmpte
```

Comment: That message pertains to libavformat linked by mplayer - as it says `libavformat version 57.25.100 (internal)`. The FFmpeg console readout relates to the ffmpeg standalone binary. mplayer has to be recompiled with https support. In the meanwhile, try `ffplay url`

Comment: Is there some way to compile mplayer using home-brew? ffmpeg does support https for sure, I checked it. How do I compile mplayer to support https?

Comment: Try mplayer lists - https://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/mailing_lists.html